# Files icon disappears from the unity launcher

Tags: unity, 16.04

I'm experiencing this behaviour on 2 separated machines (in a virtualbox vm and physically installed on another laptop):

Sometimes after I start the Files Gnome application - its corresponding button disappears from the Unity Launcher couple seconds after it's started. So if I minimize the application - I have no chance to close the application rather than killing its process with `kill`.

That's how it looks like:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced it? Is it a bug or some tricky configuration option?

If it's a bug - where should I report it?

PS: I've filed a bug for that https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1565194

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  All bugs are reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/.  Of course, Ubuntu 16.04 is not officially released until April 21, 2016, so I am not sure how they would handle any bugs yet.

Comment: @Terrance "so I am not sure how they would handle any bugs yet" --- yep, that's why I asked. But let's see if the report is replied with anything useful anyway.

Comment: I agree.  Hopefully they can get it fixed then before the release.  =)

Comment: Looks like Nautilus simply crashes. I am pretty sure icons on your desktop (if any) will disappear as well. What you could try is remove `~/.config/nautilus`, immediately log out, and back in.

Comment: @JacobVlijm it does not crash - it is running until I explicitly close the window.

Comment: Ah, I see, that kills my theory :( Really think it is a Unity bug then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue. I just upgraded from ubuntu 14.04.
Resolved by removing files from the launcher then draging it from the dash to the launcher again

Answer (score 1):

It does work as anas has said but after doing so right click it and open a new window.

If you do not open a new window what happens is if you click the one in the dash a second icon will appear and then it will disappear when you close out of the opened one from the dash. No arrows will appear next to the one you dragged from the dash.

Once you have right clicked and opened a new window arrows will appear next to the one dragged from the dash.

Answer (score 0):

It is [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1578792). As a workaround:

- Unlock "Files" from launcher if it is
- Open a terminal (or ALT+F2)
- Enter `nautilus`
- Lock that newly spawned launcher to panel

Comment: Well, my bug report was prior to that :-)

Answer (score -1):

**Hello I can recommend you to try out  [plank dock](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/install-plank-dock-and-plank-themer.html)
where you can pin your current windows/ programs and few others.**

I am personally not using dash at all, just having it hidden, mac style [macbuntu](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html)

Comment: Sorry, but irrelevant.