# Nautilus file manger is not showing up in taskbar

Tags: nautilus, files, filemanager, taskbar

When I open up natuilus ( the default ubuntu file manger), the icon does not appear in my task manager so when I want to go back to that same session, I simply cannot. I wonder if this is a known problem. using 16.04.

Comment: It is the same as this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/752915/files-icon-disappears-from-the-unity-launcher ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same issue